# c# - how to add Collection changed event to windows forms application

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datagrid

I am looking for an event that triggers when the number of rows change, i.e. the user adds a row or deletes a row in any way. I am trying to use this code, but it's not working.

designer.cs

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows.CollectionChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCollectionChangedEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CollectionChanged);
```

form1.cs

```
    private void dataGridView1_CollectionChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the the [DataGridView.UserDeletedRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletedrow) and the [DataGridView.UserAddedRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.useraddedrow) events?

I also was able to get your CollectionChanged Event to fire by setting up the handler like this.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.dataGridView1.Rows.CollectionChanged += new CollectionChangeEventHandler(Rows_CollectionChanged);
}

void Rows_CollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangeEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Print(e.Action.ToString()); // to use Debug.Print function add a using System.Diagnostics to your program
    Debug.Print(e.Element.ToString());
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)e.Element;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two events available directly on the DataGridView

[`RowsAdded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded)

[`RowsRemoved`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsremoved)

However, these only fire when the user is adding or removing rows using the DataGridView features. If you want to detect a row added or removed from the underlying DataTable (etc) then you'll need to handle the events your collection exposes.

`DataTable`s have two events:

[`TableNewRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.tablenewrow)

[`RowDeleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowdeleted)

If these events are not what you are looking for, then you can find the complete DataGridView event documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4dwfh7x